# Java & Linux Issue

Tags: java, linux

Was wondering if anyone could help to figure out why this doesn't want to work on Linux.
Cause the game this updater is for is made for Mac, Linux and Windows so trying to make it that everyone can use it without any problems.

The program works perfectly on windows without a single error.
I got my friend that uses Linux to run it with everything required and it just detects the folder and stops.

```
package mu;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileFilter;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;

public class Main extends JFrame
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2627728992434582295L;
    public String site;
    public String filename;
    public static String[] mods = new String[99];
    public static String[] Cver = new String[99]; //Current Version
    public static String[] webs = new String[99]; //Web Address to file
    public static String[] Nver = new String[99]; //New Version
    public static int num = 0;
    public static final void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        folders();
    }
    public static void folders(){
        File dir = new File("").getAbsoluteFile();
        File[] files = dir.listFiles();
        FileFilter filefilter= new FileFilter(){
            public boolean accept(File file){
                return file.isDirectory();
            }
        };
        files = dir.listFiles(filefilter);
        System.out.println(files.length + " Mods found!");
        if(files.length == 0){
        }else{
            for(int i=0; i<files.length; i++){
                File filename = files[i];
                Freader(filename);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void Freader(File dir){
        File f = new File(dir + "\\version.txt");
        if(f.exists()){
            try{
                FileReader in = new FileReader(f);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);
                String str;
                int line = 0;
                while((str = br.readLine()) != null){
                    if(line == 0){
                        mods[num] = str;
                        System.out.println(mods[num]);
                    }else if(line == 1){
                        Cver[num] = str;
                        System.out.println(Cver[num]);
                    }else if(line == 2){
                        webs[num] = str;
                        System.out.println(webs[num]);
                        Oreader(webs[num]);
                    }
                    line++;
                }
                num++;
                br.close();
            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else{
        }
    }
    public static void Oreader(String dir){
        try{
            URL url = new URL(dir);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            String str;
            int line = 0;
            boolean newVer = false;
            while((str = in.readLine()) != null){
                if (line == 0){
                    Nver[num] = str;
                    if(!Cver[num].equals(Nver[num])){
                        System.out.println(Nver[num]);
                        System.out.println("New version available!");
                        newVer = true;
                    }
                }else if(newVer && line == 1){
                    DL(str, (mods[num]+Nver[num].toString() + ".zip"));
                }
                line++;
            }
            in.close();
        }catch(MalformedURLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void DL(String web,String name){
        File dir = new File("").getAbsoluteFile();
        float Precent = 0;
        JFrame frm = new JFrame();
        JProgressBar current = new JProgressBar(0,100);
        current.setSize(394,25);
        current.setValue(0);
        current.setStringPainted(true);
        frm.setTitle("Mod Updater");
        frm.add(current);
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel(mods[num],JLabel.CENTER);
        frm.add(label1).setBounds(0, 10, 394, 50);
        frm.setSize(400,100);
        frm.setLayout(null);
        frm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frm.setResizable(false);
        frm.setVisible(true);
        String site = web;
        try{
            URL url = new URL(site);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            int filesize = connection.getContentLength();
            float totalDataRead=0;
            java.io.BufferedInputStream in = new java.io.BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
            java.io.FileOutputStream fos = new java.io.FileOutputStream(name);
            java.io.BufferedOutputStream bout = new java.io.BufferedOutputStream(fos,1024);
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            int i=0;
            while((i=in.read(data,0,1024))>=0){
                totalDataRead=totalDataRead+i;
                bout.write(data,0,i);
                Precent=(totalDataRead*100)/filesize;
                current.setValue((int)Precent);
                if(Precent == 100){
                    extract(dir + "\\" +name);
                }
            }
            bout.close();
            in.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            javax.swing.JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog((Component)null,e.getMessage(),"Error", javax.swing.JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION);
        }
    }
    public static void extract(String filePath){
            File dir = new File("").getAbsoluteFile();
            FileInputStream fis = null;
            ZipInputStream zipIs = null;
            ZipEntry zEntry = null;
            boolean dirs = false;
            try {
                fis = new FileInputStream(filePath);
                zipIs = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(fis));
                while((zEntry = zipIs.getNextEntry()) != null){
                    try{
                        byte[] tmp = new byte[4*1024];
                        FileOutputStream fos = null;
                        String opFilePath = dir +"/"+zEntry.getName();
                        if(zEntry.isDirectory()){
                            dirs = new File(zEntry.getName()).mkdirs();
                        }else{
                            System.out.println("Extracting file to "+opFilePath);
                            fos = new FileOutputStream(opFilePath);
                            int size = 0;
                            while((size = zipIs.read(tmp)) != -1){
                                    fos.write(tmp, 0 , size);
                            }
                        }
                        fos.flush();
                        fos.close();
                    } catch(Exception ex){
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                zipIs.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        System.out.println("Finished");
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue?

Comment: "Doesn't want to work" is a little vague. What error message are you getting when trying to run it on Linux?

Comment: What doesn't work? If I came to you with 20+ lines of code and said "This doesn't work fix it" I hope your first question would be "what is the error"? The same applies here. If you couldn't answer the question with more details then we can't either.

Comment: I'll not echo what others have already said, as I think you get the idea. I'll simply add that since you appear to be doing a lot of file system stuff, keep in mind the differences between linux and other operating systems like windows. Linux is case sensitive, for example. Additionally, don't hard code path separators, use `File.pathSeparator()`, or even better `new File(somePath, filename)`. And so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your problematic line is here:

`extract(dir + "\\" +name);`

As far as I can remember, Linux does not recognize a backslash in it's path. On the other hand, Windows does recognize a forward slash. Also, double slashes are redundant. Try replacing that bit with '/' instead.

Even better, as @Teeg suggested, use `File.pathSeparator()` for a truly cross-platform solution. Here's a quote from him:

> Additionally, don't hard code path separators, use
>   File.pathSeparator(), or even better new File(somePath, filename)

But this is only a guess, we need more info on the problem you are trying to solve.

Edit: found a few other places with wrong slashes. Won't list em all. Search and replace.

Comment: A single "/" will do :-)

Comment: @GyroGearless, true, although it really doesn't matter here. Either will work.

Comment: Sadly no errors so its probably the separators, so using file.separator s  now   Getting him to test it, right now and I guess it works.   Guess I'll be using file.separator  from now on.   Thank you guys.

Comment: @TimothyGreason, don't mention it, glad to help.